# XSD Name-unknown optional elements with name-known optional elements

Tags: xsd

Starting from a year-basis evolving XSD/XML, I want to write a simpler XSD, only targeting elements that won't be modified or removed, which can validate XML from the complete XSD.

To make it simple:

With this XML:

```
<root>
    <unknown1/>
    <known2/>
    <unknown2/>
    <known1/>
    <unknown3/>
    <unknown4/>
</root>
```

And this XSD:

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="unknown1"  minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="unknown2" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="unknown3" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="unknown4" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="known1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="known2" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:element name="root">
</xsd:schema>
```

I want to make something like:

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:any processControl="skip" />
        <xsd:element name="known1" />
        <xsd:element name="known2" />
</xsd:schema>
```

This XSD is not valid as `xsd:any` can only appear in `xsd:sequence` or `xsd:choice`

I wonder how I can validate the original XML file with a similar simple XSD

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `xs:choice` of known1, 2, and `xs:any`, and set `maxOccurs` to `unbounded`.

**Edit**: This still only handles optional case, but I realized you don't have to nest `xs:choice` in a `xs:sequence`.

Comment: and what if i got a XML without know1 and/or know2? this will validate and that will be wrong

Comment: so known1, and known2 are required but the rest are optional? the title says "Name-unknown optional elements with name-known optional elements" so I am confused.

Comment: My apologies, they're optional. what will you recommend with non-optional elements?
And even with optional element, if I have known1 & known2 plus extra elements (unknown1 for example), that won't do the right thing

Comment: If using XML Schema is not a requirement, you could try Relax NG, which has a concept of [interleaving](http://relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2815185) and [name class](http://relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2816343).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working schema that allows

- free order between `<known1>` and `<known2>` elements
- omitting `<known1>` or `<known2>` (or both)
- unbounded amount of any other elements before, after or in between them

Do note that you must restrict the elements allowed by `<xs:any>` to some other namespace than `<known1>` or `<known2>`. Otherwise the schema will became unambiguous because `<xs:any>` would also allow `<known1>` or `<known2>`. Another thing to notice is that here we need to sometimes set the `minOccurs` attribute on the `<xs:choice>` or `<xs:sequence>` in order to keep the schema deterministic.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="skip" />
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="known1" />
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="skip" />
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
              <xs:element name="known2" />
              <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="skip" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="known2" />
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="skip" />
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
              <xs:element name="known1" />
              <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="skip" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: use XSD 1.1

Then your proposal will work. More specific:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>

    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:all>
            <!-- Required -->
            <xs:element name="known1" type="xs:string"/>
            <!-- Optional -->
            <xs:element name="known2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="known3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <!-- Unknown -->
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```